# A job application asks for a "sample of current scholarship," what is this?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application

I am filling out a job application, which asks to attach a "sample of current scholarship."

What is this?

I am guessing this means something like a published paper, but as a new PhD graduate, does the thesis count?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Scholarship" is effectively a synonym for "research".  Send something like:

- a published paper
- a preprint of an unpublished paper
- your thesis, or one or more chapters from it

Your advisor may have advice as to what would be best.